# Windows XP in Hyper-V (Host Win 10) No Mouse

Tags: windows-xp, hyper-v

I created a new Windows XP VM in Hyper-V running on a Windows 10 host. I'm getting the "Mouse input not captured" message. I don't have "Insert Integration Services Disk" in the Action menu. Under the VM's settings, every option under "Integration Services" is checked. How do I get the mouse to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP is not supported in Windows 10 Hyper-V.  See:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0184afd8-ac12-4d49-b4b9-d2411019817c/will-windows-xp-run-on-hyperv-with-10-pro?forum=win10itprovirt

The second post down says you can make it work even though not supported.

VMware Workstation supports XP and mouse / keyboard. I have it here and that is an alternative for you to try.